# What causes this error: Error: Required configuration or TAPOS fields are not present

Tags: nodeos, eosjs, error

What causes this error?

`Error: Required configuration or TAPOS fields are not present`

I am pushing transactions to a mainnet block producer and I am receiving this error intermittently.

Any help would be appreciated.

---

**Update 1**

Appears to be coming from eosjs https://github.com/EOSIO/eosjs/blob/1fa93d48f51460397b80db2b5c8579dc89873bc4/src/eosjs-api.ts#L363

Happens when something like `{ blocksBehind: 3, expireSeconds: 30 }` is not attached as the config for the transaction, though I am including that.

---

**Update 2**

Could be related to this bug https://github.com/EOSIO/eosjs/issues/554. Updating from eosjs 20 to 22 to see if it fixes it.

---

**Update 3**

Seems the bug was fixed in version 20 https://github.com/EOSIO/eosjs/blob/4292225daa37e31fbb537d15d6eacf3b390470b5/package.json.  Browsing the repo from the commit's hash where the bug was fixed.

---

**Update 4**

Issue resolved by updating to eosjs 22.

Answer (score 0):

Updating to eosjs 22 has resolved the issue.